# How to check enum value of an array element only if it's bool value is satisfied using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I am using the condition below to check if `myArray` has exactly one element with `isClosed = false`

```
if (myArray.Count(x => !x.isClosed) == 1) {

}
```

I would like to check and see if the only false element (from my condition above) has a `color = red`

from the enum,

```
public enum Color {red, blue, yellow};
```

So generally, I want to match the conditions firstly, testing for one false `isClosed` element and checking if that same element has `color = red`.

**UPDATE**

I want to check two things in the following order:

1. If there exists only one element say `x`, with `!isClosed`
2. if (1) is satisfied, then a check to see if the same element (that satisfied (1)), also satisfies `color = red`

Comment: As you may guess from the large number of different answers, your question is not clear. In particular, it's not clear whether you want to know if there is exactly one `!isClosed` element that has `color == Color.red`, or if there is exactly one `!isClosed` element of any color, and that one element has `color == Color.red`. You need to clarify your question.

Comment: @OnlyCodeMatters:  _"I thought I explained it clearly"_ -- Who are you? This question was posted by user Bane, not you. In any case, the statement _"I want exactly one !isClosed with color == Color.red "_ could be interpreted either way. (By the way: when responding to a user named `<username>` in comments, you should include `@<username>` so that the user is notified that there is a comment for them.)

Comment: I think the task is simple enough for you to attempt it yourself, then post the code if you have problems.

Comment: After going around a few times, I'm not sure it is that simple to do an elegant LINQ method.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use &&

```
if (myArray.Count(x => !x.isClosed && x.color == Color.red) == 1) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your description is correct then you actually need to check two conditions.

```
if (myArray.Any(x => !x.isClosed && x.color==Color.Red) &&
    myArray.Count(x => !x.isClosed) == 1)) {

}
```

In the hope of avoiding any other drive by downvotes, here is an explanation:

Question states two requirements:

1. **Exactly one** element with isClosed = false

`myArray.Count(x => !x.isClosed) == 1)`

2. If the only false element (from condition above) has a `color = red`

`myArray.Any(x => !x.isClosed && x.color==Color.Red)`

If the OP is looking for a single statement, then the above can be combined into the following query:

```
myArray.Any(x => 
  !x.isClosed && 
  x.color == Color.Red && 
  myArray.Count(y => !y.isClosed) == 1)
```

Comment: Your "single statement" is worse than the "as two version" - that `Count` is going to be called for every row looked at in the `Any`, making it an `O(n^2)` instead of an `O(n)`.

Comment: @Clockwork: _"that Count is going to be called for every row looked at in the Any"_ -- I'm not saying I think the single-statement version is really a significant improvement over the originally-proposed version, but it's not O(n^2) either. The `Count()` method is called only after the first two tests pass, and if the returned value is `1`, that's the only time it's called.

Comment: @clockwork-muse the single statement is (computationally) identical to the original although it does look ugly. Are you able to suggest a more elegant method which will still address both requirements?

Comment: And now that the OP has clarified the question, ironically, this is the only answer of the **four** remaining undeleted that answers the question the OP intended to ask. (A [fifth one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45022340) did as well, but the owner deleted it after getting down-voted.

Comment: _"the single statement is (computationally) identical to the original"_ -- just to clarify: it is _potentially_ identical. But, consider the scenario where _all_ elements in `myArray` meet the first two conditions (`!isClosed` and `color == Color.red` -- note capitalization of `red`). Then it actually will run in O(n^2) time. Presumably this is an unlikely scenario, but your first version does avoid that worst-case behavior.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Point taken - but I cant think of any obvious ways to avoid that. Any ideas?

Comment: Personally, I find the question uninteresting. A non-LINQ implementation could be written to achieve the same goal, without the need to solicit advice from the Stack Overflow community. I'm not a big fan of most questions that take the form of "do this, but in LINQ". That said, if I were to answer this question, I'd use the `Enumerable.Aggregate()` method, which would allow a single pass through the collection while computing both the count of `!isClosed` elements, and the count of `color == Color.red` elements. A count of 1 for both at the end would meet the OP's criteria for a `true` result.

Comment: (Just to be clear, the count of `color == Color.red` elements is only for those elements which are _also_ `!isClosed`.)

Comment: I think this actually completely doesn't do what the question states. This answer checks if the first open (`!isClosed`) item is red and then check to see if only 1 item is open. In lots of cases there will be extra testing.

Comment: @NetMage: _"This answer checks if the first open (!isClosed) item is red"_ -- no, that's not true. The `Any()` method will inspect all elements until the whole predicate returns `true`. Even if more than one element has `!isClosed`, it will not call `Count()` until the first element that is both `!isClosed` _and_ `color == Color.red` is found.

Comment: But then `Count` will go through and test those same elements a second time to see if they are `!isClosed`.

Answer (score 0):

Try optimized version:

```
bool result = myArray.Where (x => x.isClosed == false && x.color == Color.red)
                     .Take  (2) // we need nax 2 elements to obtain the result
                     .Count () == 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

LINQ isn't really designed for side effects, and this could be done much more effectively without it, but nothing says you can't have them:

```
int openIndex = -1;
var openCount = myArray.Select((o, i) => new { i, o }).Where(x => !x.o.isClosed).Select(io => { openIndex = io.i; return io.o; }).Count();
if (openCount == 1 && myArray[openIndex].color == Color.red) {
    // found open & red at myArray[openIndex]
}
```

But it would probably be best to just use code:

```
var openIndex = -1;
int openCount = 0;
for (int j1 = 0; j1 < myArray.Length; ++j1)
    if (!myArray[j1].isClosed) {
        openIndex = j1;
        if (++openCount > 1)
            break; // skip out early if bad
    }
if (openCount == 1)
    if (myArray[openIndex].color == Color.red)
        // found!
```

With some more thought, I think this LINQ is more elegant and reasonable:

```
var openIndexes = Enumerable.Range(0, myArray.Length).Where(index => !myArray[index].isClosed).ToList();
if (openIndexes.Count == 1)
    if (myArray[openIndexes[0]].color == Color.red)
        // found!
```

If you don't care about the found item or the order of your tests, I think @octavioccl has the right answer.